# How to add custom attributes in ldif file to be used for Embedded Ldap server

Tags: spring, selenium, ldap, spring-ldap

I am trying to use Embeded ldap server in spring to automate testing using selenium. My question is... Is it possible to have custom attributes in my ldif file and able to query the value of it? If it is possible, how? Any sample implementation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`attributes` and `objectClasses` are defined in the server schema.

- Create the custom attributes required by the LDAP client
- Create the custom objectClasses members of which can (or must) use the previously defined custom attributes
- Add the attribute and objectClass definitions to the server schema
- If the server does not support dynamic schema modification, restart the server.

Consult the server documentation as required to accomplish the above tasks.